# fscanf c++ equivalent

Tags: c++, c

I would like to translate the following C code to C++.

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen("./filename", "r");
int i = 0;
fscanf(fp, "%d\n", &i);
uint16_t j = (uint16_t) i;
```

This is what I came up with this:

```
  ifstream file;
  string filename = "./filename";

  file.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);
  errno = 0;
  if (file.fail()) {
      int tmp = errno;
      std::cout << file.c_str () << " not found: strerror(" << tmp << "): " << strerror(tmp) );
  }
  int i = 0;
  file >> i >> std::endl;       
  uint16_t j = (uint16_t) i;
```

I would like to know whether the syntax is correct or improvable and more importantly whether it's safe against all kinds of inputs.

Comment: First of all I'd say try it.  If there's errors, then ask about those specifically, rather than "is this right" to the community.  Try different inputs against both programs, and see which fail with which programs, and why they're different.

Comment: Or you could just leave the C code as-is. C++ is a superset of C.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: depends on the C++ version. C++03 did not have the C99 `uint16_t` and not everyone has switched to C++11 yet.

Comment: I was trying to make it safer and easier to read for c++ users. I am not sure about the syntax std::endl when used with a file. In fact eclipse says "invalid overload".

Comment: That `endl` shouldn't be there. `cin` will go on to the next line anyways.

Comment: `endl` calls `operator<<` and `flush()`, neither which are defined on an `istream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int read_int(const std::string file_name) {
    std::ifstream file(file_name); //the file will close itself on destruction
    std::uint16_t i;
    //extract type, don't worry about what it is it will either compile or not
    if(!(file >> i)) { //Catch failure
         //or however you wish to deal with it.
         throw std::runtime_error("can't read file");
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    try{
        std::uint16_t i=read_int("./filepath");
        //do with i...
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
         std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
         return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note if you do not have C++11 then you will need to use `c_str()` to open the file, but the string method is prefered.

EDIT: fstream close themselves, there is no need to close it yourself, the functionality is there incase you do have to do that however it is far better to rely on RAII semantics:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

RAII dictates that you should open the file on construction and it will close on destructions, this ensures that there isn't any invalid (exclude EOF, file not found...) fstream object preventing bugs. RAII is a fundamental construct in C++ and should be used where ever resources are concerned.

The docs for the fstream destructors is here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream

> destructs the basic_fstream and the associated buffer, closes the file

Comment: @chris, thanks again, I have just come in from the rain it is too early for this stuff. :S

Comment: Can you please forward me to a documentation where it says that the file will close itself on destruction, when opened like this ? I just can't find it...

Answer (score 2):

The exact equivalent would be:

```
std::ifstream fs( "./filename" );
int i = 0;
fs >> i >> std::ws;
uint16_t j = i;
```

Whether this is what you really want is another question: the use of a
`"\n"` in the format string for `fscanf` suggests (to me, at least) that
you really want to read a single `'\n'`, and not arbitrary white space;
what the `"\n"` means in `fscanf`, however, is to skip up to the next
non-whitespace.  (In the case of interactive input, this can be a real
problem, since you won't return from your `scanf`—or my 
replacement above—until you've encountered a non-white space
character or end of file.  For input from a file, it may not be an
issue.)

When reading line oriented input, the classical solution is to use
`std::getline`, and then an `std::istringstream` to parse it.