# Fscanf is not reading expected values from last line of file (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, c++11, scanf

The code below is file reading function for my task scheduling program. Everything is OK, until it tries to read sequence of numbers (ex 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) representing deadlines. Instead of ints some random numbers are added to the table "Deadlines". Does anyone know solution for this problem?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <map>
    #include <time.h>
    using namespace std;
    class Task{
        public:
            string Name;
            int Number;
            int Operation_Time_Machine_One;
            int Operation_Time_Machine_Two;
            int Task_Deadline;
    };
    int Maximum_Time_Between_IDE;
    int IDE_Duration;
    int Read_File(){
        string FileName= "";
        cout << "Please enter file name (with .txt):\t";
        cin >> FileName;
        std::vector<Task> Task_Vector;
        FILE* OpenedFile = fopen(FileName.c_str(),"r");
        int Number_Of_Tasks=0;
        int Duration_Of_Operation_One =0;
        int Duration_Of_Operation_Two =0;
        if( OpenedFile == NULL){
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else{
                fscanf(OpenedFile,"%d", &Number_Of_Tasks);
                for (int i=0; i<= Number_Of_Tasks;i++){
                    Duration_Of_Operation_One=0;
                    Duration_Of_Operation_Two=0;
                    fscanf(OpenedFile, "%d, %d", &Duration_Of_Operation_One, &Duration_Of_Operation_Two);
                    Task New_task;
                    New_task.Name ="task" ;
                    New_task.Number = (i+1);
                    New_task.Operation_Time_Machine_One = Duration_Of_Operation_One;
                    New_task.Operation_Time_Machine_Two = Duration_Of_Operation_Two;
                    New_task.Task_Deadline =0;
                    Task_Vector.push_back(New_task);
                }
                fscanf(OpenedFile,"%d", &Maximum_Time_Between_IDE);
                fscanf(OpenedFile,"%d", &IDE_Duration);
                int Deadlines[Number_Of_Tasks];
//from now it's gettig weird
               for(int i=0; i<=Number_Of_Tasks;i++){
                    fscanf(OpenedFile,"%d, ", &Deadlines[i]);
                }
                for(int i=0; i<=Number_Of_Tasks;i++){
                    cout<<Deadlines[i]<<endl;
                }
        }
        fclose(OpenedFile);

        return 0;
    }
    int main()
    {
        clock_t time;
        time = clock();
        std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
        Read_File();
        time = clock() - time;
        printf ("Time of algorithm %f seconds.\n",((float)time)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        return 0;
    }
```

Sample input:

```
5
74, 64
27, 74
69, 47
35, 54
101, 86
102
6
113, 242, 344, 144, 513
```

Comment: You've posted too much of irrelevant code. Please create an MVCE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `fscanf()` returns a value indicating success.  Code is having some input troubles  --> check the return value of `fscanf()`.

Comment: Like you suggested, I checked and when it gets into the loop the file has error code msvcrt!_iob+95?

Comment: By the way, you don't need `fsanf` in C++. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10283841/2721583

Answer (score 3):

There are some errors..

> `int Deadlines[Number_Of_Tasks]`

VLA's are not allowed in C++. Therefore you should remove the `C++` tag, or use `std::vector` everywhere you want a VLA. i.e `std::vector<int> Deadlines(Number_Of_Tasks);`

> `for(int i=0; i <= Number_Of_Tasks; i++)`
>
> ```
>  .... Deadlines[i]
> ```

you're exceeding the bounds of the array, which leads to undefined behavior. What you want to do is (in both the last two loops):

```
for(int i=0; i < Number_Of_Tasks; i++)
              ^^^
```

Finally, don't combine C and C++ which are two different programming languages. Choose one of them for your program and stick to it.

Comment: That is the solution! Thak you so much !

Comment: @AnnaTiko, it's preferred behaviour to mark the answer as the right answer than to make only a comment about it.  Please, mark it as this allows the game of StackOverflow to continue.  This will allow your responder to earn reputation points and be selected as a good answerer.